# How to merge pandas dataframes after renaming columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a code that merged 2 dataframes that had all columns in uppercase. I need to adjust the code to merge the dataframes but now 1 comes with columns in lowercase and the other doesn't.

I wrote the following code to change the columns names to lowercase, and then changed the merge to lowercase also, but no i get a Key error: 'code'

```
df_small = df_small.rename(columns=str.lower)
common = df_small.merge(df_big,on=['code'])
```

Comment: please post both column names in each dataframe

Comment: Instead of on='code', you should use left_on='key_of_df_small' and right_on='key_of_df_big'.

Answer (score 0):

First to 'lower' the column names you can use:

```
df_small.columns = df_small.columns.str.lower()
```

I think that your code for lowercasing the column names is doing something wrong. Try mine above